# Node application is not working after deployed to server

Tags: node.js, express, router

I have node application which is running correctly in local machine, but when I deploy this application to server, then only '/' route is working, Other routers are not working.

When I run this on my local machine, it is working fine.

[image]

Here is another example

[image]

But **when I deploy this to server, it is not working**
[image]

Only home route is working on server.

Below is my app.js

```
//routers : Masters
app.use('/masters', masterRoutes);     

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json('Application is up and running on port 4003');
});
```

and I have added route in 'routes/masters.js'

```
router.get('/categories', categoryController.getCategories);
```

When I deploy this to server, I have also restarted pm2.
Port 4003 is also opened on server.

What I am missing ?

Comment: Since it's working locally and not working remotely the code almost surely doesn't have anything to do with it: chances are more likely that it's about the deployment!

Comment: In the last screenshot the error references `//masters/categories`. You have a double backslash. That looks like the problem, check where you define your requests in the frontend

Comment: thank you caffeinated.tech and Nir for your comments, there was problem with deployment. Nginx configuration were wrong, I was missing '/' in location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem, Nginx configuration was set wrongly.
Added slash '/' after location as below

```
 location /_api/{
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:4003/";
 }
```